# SQL - Selecting with text and datetime data types

Tags: sql-server

I am having a problem when attempting to get a SQL statement working when pulling datetime column data.

The following statement works fine:

```
select 'sometext ''' + nvarcharcolumn + ''' sometext' from sourcetable
```

However when attempting with a datetime data type I get a problem

```
select 'sometext ''' + datetimecolumn + ''' sometext' from sourcetable
```

The above statement fails with the error:

```
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
```

I have been playing around with the cast/convert functionality but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Could anyone give me the correct syntax to get this working?

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: `datetimecolumn` columns is of `datetime` type. you cannot concatenate it with string directly. you need to convert this into `VARCHAR` first using `CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),datetimecolumn)` or using appropriate style based on your requirement

Comment: The way the error message is phrased suggests that you are using the given sql as a subquery to set the value of a datetime column (just guessing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of converting `datetimecolumn` to `varchar`, SQL Server tries to convert your texts to `datetime`, which does not work.

Convert `datetimecolumn` to varchar:

```
select 'sometext ''' + convert(varchar, datetimecolumn) + ''' sometext' from sourcetable
```

To get a special format for your converted date and time, you can use the third parameter of `CONVERT()` as described here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187928.aspx#languageReferenceRemarksToggle